# How to ignore or override a request header in .NET Core Web Api?

Tags: .net-core, http-headers, asp.net-core-webapi

I have built a simple REST api using .NET Core Web Api. Everything works great except when ran in a particular environment that requires the requests to go through a proxy. This proxy sets the `Connection` header to a value other than `keep-alive` or `close`, which causes the Web Api application to respond with a `400 Bad Request`. I have no control over this environment and MUST go through the proxy.

How can I configure Web Api so that it ignores the header provided by the HTTP Request and instead always uses one that I specify?

Comment: You can't. It doesn't even make sense that you could, as the whole issue is that the server is rejecting the request, so how could it rewrite headers on something it has rejected long before any code that would do that would be run?